Do not use a Hilla/React layout in a Flow View with Vaadin 24.4.x
I have a project that uses the Vaadin 24.4.x release where Hilla is integrated directly with Vaadin. With this, I use a React-based layout in src/main/frontend/@layout.tsx that implements the AppLayout with a side drawer for the navigation menu.
import {createMenuItems, useViewConfig} from '@vaadin/hilla-file-router/runtime.js';
import {effect, signal} from '@vaadin/hilla-react-signals';
import {AppLayout, DrawerToggle, Icon, SideNav, SideNavItem} from '@vaadin/react-components';
import {Suspense, useEffect} from 'react';
import {Link, Outlet, useLocation, useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom';

const defaultTitle = document.title;
const documentTitleSignal = signal('');
effect(() => {
    document.title = documentTitleSignal.value;
});

// Publish for Vaadin to use
(window as any).Vaadin.documentTitleSignal = documentTitleSignal;

export default function MainLayout() {
    const currentTitle = useViewConfig()?.title ?? defaultTitle;
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const location = useLocation();

    useEffect(() => {
        documentTitleSignal.value = currentTitle;
    }, [currentTitle]);

    return (
        <AppLayout primarySection="drawer">
            <div slot="drawer" className="flex flex-col justify-between h-full p-m">
                <header className="flex flex-col gap-m">
                    <Link to={"/"} className={"font-semibold text-l text-header decoration-none"}>JIMI</Link>
                    <SideNav onNavigate={({ path }) => navigate(path!)} location={location}>
                        {createMenuItems().map(({ to, title, icon }) => (
                            <SideNavItem path={to} key={to} className={`item-${to.replace(/^\//, '')}`}>
                                {icon ? <Icon src={icon} slot="prefix"></Icon> : <></>}
                                {title}
                            </SideNavItem>
                        ))}
                    </SideNav>
                </header>
            </div>

            <DrawerToggle slot="navbar" aria-label="Menu toggle"></DrawerToggle>
            <h1 slot="navbar" className="text-l m-0">
                {documentTitleSignal}
            </h1>

            <Suspense>
                <Outlet />
            </Suspense>
        </AppLayout>
    );
}

Next, I have a login page defined with Vaadin Flow that consists of a Button and some text to initialize a Google OAuth login flow. To enable a basic auth login in my testing environment, I utilize @ConditionalOnProperty to define either one of two Login pages (this example - Oauth - and a basic auth with username and password).
@ConditionalOnProperty(
    prefix = "com.example.testing",
    name = ["form-login-enabled"],
    havingValue = "false",
    matchIfMissing = true,
)
@Route("login")
@AnonymousAllowed
class OAuthLoginView : VerticalLayout() {
  ...
}

Before the change to add a Hilla layout, I used a Vaadin Flow Layout that was simply not used in the login pages. However, now I use the Hilla parent layout, I seem to be unable to disable this for the login pages.
The goal of this question is to not use the @layout.tsx layout for my /login pages, but just have a plain <div> for that, so that the login pages keep being clean.
I have tried a Vaadin 24.5.x alpha version where some automatic layout features are added. Mainly the @Layout, but also the @Route(..autoLayout=false). That does not seem to be helping. It is always being wrapped with the root layout in src/main/frontend/@layout.tsx
